# How to load image from url into imageview in widget using picasso

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, widget, picasso

I tried to load the image into the imageview on the widget using Picasso but when i run imageview return blank, no image is displayed just white blank

[image: blank image]

this is my code

```
internal class StackRemoteViewsFactory(private val context: Context, intent: Intent) :
    RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    private val appWidgetId: Int = intent.getIntExtra(
        AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
        AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
    )

    ......

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
        val rv = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_favorite_item)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Picasso.get().load(data[position].image_path)
            .into(rv, R.id.img_widget_banner, intArrayOf(appWidgetId))
        }

        return rv

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your Picasso code.
First check data[position].imagepath return the correct image path.
If you still have the problem then try to show image into only one view.
For example you use: 
rv is a image view

```
Picasso.get()
.load(data[position].image_path)
.into(rv)
```